# Why is the ip address 10.1.1.97 routed to 10.1.1.64/26 network

Tags: ipv4, subnet

I am studying for the CCNA Routing and Switching.  While taking a practice test I was asked the following question...

Question: Your router has just received a packet that is destined to 10.1.1.97. 
Which entry in the routing table will be used to forward the packet?
A. 10.1.1.0/25
B. 10.1.1.64/27
C. 0.0.0.0/0
D. 10.1.1.64/26
E. 10.1.1.32/27
F. 10.1.1.0/24
G. 10.1.1.80/28

I was confused by this question because I calculated that answer A, D and F were all viable answers.

Here is my work...

Answer A: Network ID = 10.1.1.0 | Range = .1 - .126 | Broadcast = 10.1.1.127

Answer D: Network ID = 10.1.1.64 | Range = .65 - .126 | Broadcast = 10.1.1.127

Answer F: Network ID = 10.1.1.0 | Range = .1 - .254 | Broadcast = 10.1.1.255

The Practice test said that the answer is D. 10.1.1.64/26.

Can someone explain why this is the correct answer instead of A or F seeing how (by my calculations) the address 10.1.1.97 also falls within their ranges.

Comment: Well... 10.1.1.64/26 is the most specific one that works... the address does fit in the ranges of those other two, but those two are broader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routing works with longest prefix matching. The number behind the slash is the prefix length. Looking at the prefixes that contain the correct address the lengths are:

- A: 25
- D: 26
- F: 24

Of these D is the longest matching prefix, so that one will be used. A and F are aggregates that contain D, but D is the most specific.

Comment: Thank you! I learned something!

Comment: In that case please mark the answer as accepted :)